# Java - cannot find d3d libraries

Tags: java, javafx, module, runtime-error

I'm trying to use graphic-acceleration in a java-fx application:

this is the error I got:

```
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no prism_d3d in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/jni, /lib, /usr/lib]
```

This is the script I launch:

```
VIDEO=/home/user/test.mp4
FX_PATH=$(pwd)/javafx17-sdk/

## NOTE: Dprism.order=d3d is what I'm trying to use
java \
 -Dprism.order=d3d,sw \
 -Dprism.forceGPU=true \
 -Dprism.verbose=true \
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
 --module-path "${FX_PATH}/lib/" \
 --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH \
 --add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED \
 --add-opens javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.charts=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.iio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.iio.common=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.impl=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils=ALL-UNNAMED \
 --class-path "${FX_PATH}/lib/;" \
 -jar SimpleFxVideo.jar ${VIDEO}
```

This is the project I'm compiling (and exporting as runnable jar with eclipse)

[GIT Repo](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx-demo.git)

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS with openJDK 11.0.16

TL:DR
this is the full trace of the error

```
# Script.sh
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw 
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no prism_d3d in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/jni, /lib, /usr/lib]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2673)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:166)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:54)
    at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.lambda$static$0(D3DPipeline.java:54)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.<clinit>(D3DPipeline.java:50)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:92)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
 vsync: true vpipe: false
```

Comment: Looks like you have a package problem! To determine the error you need to share more information of those classes!

Comment: See the git repo attached (... sorry, I've seen only now the name is nonsense, fixed)

Comment: [Direct 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct3D) is a windows library.  Ubuntu uses opengl as its graphics API, not direct3d.  You should not be specifying prism hints in your command line.  If your setup is capable of hardware-accelerated graphics, it will be used automatically.